# Excel: Multiple =IF calculations within one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, spreadsheet

I need to do some text comparisons in excel, about 20-50 of them.  I would like the result of these if statements to be within a single cell. Here is how I WISHED it would work:

---

=IF("Test1"="","Equal1","Not equal1")

=IF("Test1"="","Equal1","Not equal1")

=IF("Test1"="","Equal1","Not equal1")

=IF("Test1"="","Equal1","Not equal1")

---

If that did work, I would like to see the following in the cell:

---

Not Equal1

Not Equal1

Not Equal1

Not Equal1

---

Is there any way, maybe using some advanced method, to calculate multiple string comparisons like this, all within a single cell?

Comment: Are you trying to do multiple comparisons, test to see if two literals are equal, or something else?

Comment: Yes, just doing string comparisons.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me but it may be possible using an **array formula**. For example, `={SUM(IF(A1:A4<>B1:B4,1,0))}` will return the number or rows (1-4) where column A <> Column B. If you can make your question more clear I might be able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type new line characters betwen each if statement.:

```
=IF("Test1"="","Equal1","Not equal1")&"
"&IF("Test2"="","Equal2","Not equal2")&"
"&IF("Test3"="","Equal3","Not equal3")&"
"&IF("Test4"="","Equal4","Not equal4")
```

**EDIT:** Or to put new lines only after affirmative tests:

```
=IF("Test1"="","Equal1
","")&IF("Test2"="","Equal2
","")&IF("Test3"="","Equal3
","")&IF("Test4"="","Equal4
","")
```

Comment: I can not thank you enough!  This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: One other question, it it possible to remove the new line characters on some of the if statements depending on their result?

Comment: Yes, put the new line character inside the result instead of after each test.  See edits above.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a series of `IF`s within a concatenation to get them into the same cell:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF("test"="test","yes","no"),IF("test"="test2","yes","no"))
```

You'll probably want some spacing in there to make it look pretty, or a CHR(10) to get new lines (turn on wrap on the cells).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about nested-if? Where you have multiple if statement in a single cell. If so then check this out http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/tipsandfaqs/qt/nested_if.htm